# Ubuntu server API call

Tags: ubuntu, server

I have a Ubuntu server (latest version) and I have an issue. First off, I have a Class in Java IntelliJ springboot, which connects to the website bitstamps.net and gets the values for 5 crypto currencies.

When I make this REST API call to this webpage it returns:

```
{
    "response": "{\"time updated\":\"12.23 18.04.2018\",\"Cryptos\":[\"si.flawless.cryptohunt.model.CryptoCurrentValue@764763e7\",\"si.flawless.cryptohunt.model.CryptoCurrentValue@6813cb89\",\"si.flawless.cryptohunt.model.CryptoCurrentValue@52def1bb\",\"si.flawless.cryptohunt.model.CryptoCurrentValue@447d4f29\",\"si.flawless.cryptohunt.model.CryptoCurrentValue@968541a\"]}",
    "status": {
        "code": 302,
        "message": "Found"
    }
}
```

As you can see there is the si.flawless.cryptohunt.model there, which is wrong. It should display the values.

So this server is running on port 6566 which is forwarded and I can ping bitstamps.net from it normally.

BUT when I launch the rest api on my Windows 10 intelliJ program, then the REST api works normally!

Does anyone know what else I have to configure on the ubuntu server in order to get a successful API response?

We have added DNS servers, opened up the required ports(80,443,8080,6566) and it still doesn't get a response even though I can ping it!

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue.

For anyone that ever gets to this problem:
the server was somehow not returning the correct JSON, so instead of returning it in the normal REST API way, I made a private method and scheduled it to run every hour to get all crypto currency values save them to the database. This way I don't stress the API of the website I am using, since I only call it every hour.

When I want to return said values, I just have a public REST method which reads all of the data in the table for crypto currency values and return it as a list.